Does the nonabelian group of order 21 embed into $GL_6(\mathbb{F}_3)$?
Does the general linear group $G=GL_6(\mathbb{F}_3)$ of six by six invertible matrices over the field of three elements contain the nonabelian group of order 21? It would suffice to find two matrices $a$ and $b$ in $G$ such that $a$ has multiplicative order 3, the order of $b$ is 7, and $a^{-1}ba=b^2$. Do such matrices exist? Specific examples would be very much appreciated.

The symmetric group $S_7$ has a 6-dimensional representation (over any field) on the zero sum subspace $V$ of $\Bbb{F}_3^7$, stable under all coordinate permutations. Your group is a subgroup of $S_7$, and the said rep is faithful, so...

You have a nonabelian group of order $21$ in $S_7$, generated by $b = (1234567)$ and $a = (137)(254)$.
Now take the permutation module $V$ of $S_7$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. Then it has a unique $6$-dimensional irreducible submodule $W$. This gives you an embedding of $\langle a,b \rangle$ into $GL(6,3)$ as permutation matrices.

It was my second thought - the first thought was to use the fact that you can find such a subgroup in $\operatorname{Gamma L}1(3^6) = C{3^6-1} \rtimes C_6 < GL_6(3)$, as the obvious subgroup $C_7 \rtimes C_3$ in the semidirect product. But the construction with permutation matrices is more simple

Yeah! The multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{3^6}$ and then the Galois group by conjugation (Skolem-Noether, though that's a bit overkill).
